# Not getting response after Angular Fire Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm not getting response after register a user with angularfire. The user email appears on Angular's Authentication Base, but signed-in row is empty and seems not to execute the console.log function.

Here's my code, hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
    app.controller('UserRegisterCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$firebaseAuth", 
    function($scope, $http, $firebaseAuth){

        $scope.createUser = function(user_data) {
            var Auth = $firebaseAuth();
            Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_data.email, user_data.password)
            .then(function(firebaseUser){
                //This part of the code does not execute
                console.log(firebaseUser);
                console.log("User " + firebaseUser.uid + " created successfully!");

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error: ", error);
            });
    };
}]);
```

I'm using these libraries

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

And I'm using the new console. Thanks

In the Google Chrome Console I get these for the signupNewUser request:

```
{
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#SignupNewUserResponse",
 "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImZkYTFhMDhjNTAxMTM1MjRhZWQxNmJlZjQ5MzBhODI5NDQ3MmI3OTMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYXV0by1mbGVldCIsImF1ZCI6ImF1dG8tZmxlZXQiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE0NjY3MTY2MjUsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJRMkNKSDBaTDVvUlBqM05MelNCNW5Qek85SnMxIiwic3ViIjoiUTJDSkgwWkw1b1JQajNOTHpTQjVuUHpPOUpzMSIsImlhdCI6MTQ2NjcxNjYyNSwiZXhwIjoxNDY2NzIwMjI1LCJlbWFpbCI6ImF4YUBjb3JyZW8uY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7InBhc3N3b3JkIjpbImF4YUBjb3JyZW8uY29tIl0sImVtYWlsIjpbImF4YUBjb3JyZW8uY29tIl19fX0.nQphfgsRlvsxEBT9AJzH9aicRAidePomQrRvXZ7lbYI0-VyuNaU2L8Nq_wH4bu-iDLkcUG-fZIy4MgGqKgIIqczqgWq0FTWnVYqTXQykSdIdcwv77g019OiL5ek82hu7pSSNOCJ-aBj1sxfRdP6OjnrGIzrxEkQ0iID2_gbcN7yb-PkRxoes9kOdX200pcO2bEb3kLbA_HyLN9lZ1RFRnjSdi2w16P3yFAiVbr75esJ3Jb0VbaWddqACXabtVXFhAUYkqOpiswJZ98EKhJG3u3zVIoGGi_SJUFrvsPGgJHH9hm4yO2ejjSmDdYwkVQb3pag356m5hZOkhwdmHwQECg",
 "email": "axa@correo.com",
 "refreshToken": "ANflqpHqSZWPVsAE82DTF632-oVCnyGRZk2tSNKwbPOPhgudIHSsfAZa2UxkLkQwpxgWO0APmd7ZPE1hdDU2YoKADb8_0otjVRUnJPceWmj74Mwargx8sboevfloh4bmxPigxBauRuduHvOgs74vUScFCW83tUH1rWc4NXp0ppNYrMN37sqjK-PGQjlVUzONd06I-ypJqYXh",
 "expiresIn": "3600",
 "localId": "Q2CJH0ZL5oRPj3NLzSB5nPzO9Js1"
}
```

And these for the getAccountInfo request

```
{
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse",
 "users": [
  {
   "localId": "Q2CJH0ZL5oRPj3NLzSB5nPzO9Js1",
   "email": "axa@correo.com",
   "emailVerified": false,
   "providerUserInfo": [
    {
     "providerId": "password",
     "federatedId": "axa@correo.com",
     "email": "axa@correo.com",
     "rawId": "axa@correo.com"
    }
   ],
   "passwordHash": "UkVEQUNURUQ=",
   "passwordUpdatedAt": 1.466716625E12,
   "validSince": "1466716625",
   "createdAt": "1466716625000"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: what firebase and angularfire versions?

Comment: I put the information in the post. Thanks

Comment: no error messages on the logs as well? Your code looks and works good, just tried here and worked fine. only difference is that i'm using `angularfire 2.0.1` and `firebase 3.0.5` but it should not be the problem i would update just to make sure.

Comment: There's no error on the console ... I'm using google chrome console. Add the requests responses on the post. ¡Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code using `angularfire 2.0.0` and `firebase 3.0.0` and the **problem surely relies on angularfire 2.0.0**. By updating it to version 2.0.1 I was able to execute the code as expected.

**So make sure you replace your script links to the latest firebase and angularfire version**.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.5/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/66/) for demonstrating.

Comment: Thank you! problem solved. I found these link for more information

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/746

Comment: @NallelyFlores Great to see that you made progress! Do u mind setting the answer to accepted? :)